# Adjusting height of span with CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a menu for a mobile landing site.
The problem I'm having is that the items inside the divs are being set to height bigger than the containing div, which is screwing up the vertical align. I've tried many different things in order to manually set a height, but nothing is working. I've also tried setting margins and padding to 0. Nothing has worked.

Code:

```
<div id="menu">
    <div><span><h4><a class="menuItem" href="find-us.html">Find us</a></h4></span></div>
    <div><span>Promos</span></div>
    <div><span>Events</span></div>
    <div><span>Gallery</span></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/milkman15/r6VDe/1/

Comment: The first item is set as an h4 because I was also trying to different child selectors.. which also failed

Comment: Make it an `inline-block` element

Comment: where's your CSS?  Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: fiddle included now.. the fiddle screen shows how things should be, but in the browser/emulator/iPhone, things are not coming out right

Comment: `height: 100%` only works like you seem to expect on elements with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. You can change the height of your spans to a pixel height if you want to adjust them manually.

Comment: Here I thought Wild wings all goto the central website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a min height on the div and remove the css for the span inside

http://jsfiddle.net/mx28a/1/

```
#menu div{
    font-size:2.5em;
    width:93%;
    height:14%;
    margin-top:7%;
    display:inline-block;
    background:rgba(000,000,000,0.6);
    text-transform:uppercase;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

I added the min-height as the last item. Since the divs are set using percents, when the height of the screen becomes smaller your div's height also becomes smaller. Your font are simply too large for the divs so it bleeds out when you reduce the height of the window. By setting a min-height, you can stop this from happening